# Xgettext on php file in French issue with accented chars

Tags: php, gettext, xgettext

I am using xgettext on a php file with source text in French, hence with accented chars. 
Such chars are not correctly interpreted, and in the .po file produced: them all appear as little square. 
As a result, these are not matched anymore by gettext (after producing the .mo file) 
Any suggestion? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using --from-code=utf-8? xgettext defaults to ASCII encoding